# how to make autocomplete in list with link?

Tags: php, jquery

I have done autocomplete using jquery and php it's working fine .But it's coming ul dropdown, i want to be come in list with link.Please find below my code.

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#people" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags,
      minLength: 1,
    select : function(event, ui){
        // You may need to change this part, as I don't know the exact values:
        location.href = "/photograph/searchphoto/" + ui.item.value;
    }
    });
  });
</script>

<input id="people">
```

this is my out put.
[image: this is my out put]

This is what i have to do
[image: This is what i have to do]